# How to deal with the Importing Assets after downloading file from the internet?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an iOS app that can download .obj files from the server and show them. The issue I have is that once I downloaded the .obj file, Unity will start importing process which automatically stops the app. **Is there a way to avoid this or wait till it to finish and then load the file? I'm developing it for iOS**

Below is the code for downloading and loading the .obj file:

```
IEnumerator DownloadAndLoadFile(string url) { 

var uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET);
string modelSavePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources");
modelSavePath = Path.Combine(modelSavePath, docName); 

    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(modelSavePath)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(modelSavePath));
    }

 var dh = new DownloadHandlerFile(modelSavePath);
 dh.removeFileOnAbort = true; 
 uwr.downloadHandler = dh;  

AsyncOperation request = uwr.SendWebRequest();
while (!request.isDone)
    { 
        Debug.Log("Progress: " + request.progress);
        yield return null;
    }  
 if(request.isDone){

     Debug.Log("File successfully downloaded and saved to " + modelSavePath);
          // Load Main scene
        Scene s = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Main");
        if (s.isLoaded) {
                         var allObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<MainAssetSwitch>(); 
                            if (allObjects.Length > 0) { 
                                var targetobject = allObjects [0];   
                                 targetobject.SetActive(true);
                                 Object prefabReference = Resources.Load(docName);
                                  GameObject gameObjectReference = Instantiate(prefabReference) as GameObject;
                                  ameObjectReference.transform.parent = targetobject.transform; 
                            } 
            }


 }

if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
    {Debug.LogError(uwr.error);}

}
```

Here's what Unity will run automatically once I load the .obj file downloaded from internet.
[image]

I also got an error saying "ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null." due to the asset is not being imported into the Resources file after download process has finished.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no build in technologies to import `.obj` or `.fbx` models and add them to the scene on runtime in unity.

But you can use `AssetBundles` or find some assets for this purpose in the AssetStore.

An AssetBundle is an archive file containing platform specific Assets
 (Models, Textures, Prefabs, Audio clips, and even entire Scenes) that can be loaded at runtime.

Look at these documents:

`https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html`

Comment: While those links might answer the question please reproduce a compelte answer here. If the URL brakes this post becomes useless.

Comment: By the way: Your links are all for the old Unity Version 5.4. They should rather be https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html. And since OP is developing for iOS also this could be usefull: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AppThinning.html

Comment: @detHugo, thank you for noticing old links. Edited my answer.